# Creating a string of random characters

Tags: python, beginner, strings, random

I'm generating domains with random names. I used the map function because it packages the results into a list which I can then `join()` into a string but the way I used the lambda function could be confusing to people reading this later.

```
def generateHost():
  charSet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
  minLength = 5
  maxLength = 30
  length = random.randint(minLength, maxLength)

  return ''.join(map(lambda unused : random.choice(charSet), range(length)))+".com"
```

This function calls `generateHost()` 'size' times and creates an array of hosts. I could write it like the above but it would be the same problem. I wrote it with a `for` loop which I'm still not satisfied with.

```
def generateHostList(size):
  result = []
  for i in range(size):
    result += [generateHost()]
  return result
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits) suggests the following:

```
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(length))
```

It's close to your solution, but avoids having to type out the whole alphabet by using predefined values and avoids the use of map() and lambda.

Comment: Wow. Set builder notation is amazing. Any idea why 'random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(N)' doesn't have to be in brackets?

Comment: Looks like you missed `[]`

Comment: It works without the brackets when it's within joins parenthesis. I've been trying to figure out why.

Comment: @JamesFargotson The reason it works is that it is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), not a set comprehension, so the parentheses [can be omitted on calls with only one argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297653/python-generator-expression-parentheses-oddity).

Comment: @codesparkle Very cool. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 4):

A pythonic idiom is to utilize a list comprehension where possible:

```
def generateHostList(size):
    return [ generateHost() for _ in range(size) ]
```

(notice another idiom of using `_` for `unused`).

The `generateHost` itself may look confusing. The [TomBarron](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40599/tom-barron)'s solution is better.

Answer (score 3):

The other posts already answered how to generate random strings and a random list of hosts and are totally spot on.

I would just add that if this is for generating hostnames in a network, they might not be very great names. They look more like passwords, which are difficult to remember and won't be practical. I recommend a different approach, as suggested by [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/1l5utg). The idea is to pick a themes, and use a mix of them as server names. For example, you could use a mix of cartoon character names, like:

```
toystory = ('woody', 'buzz', 'jessie', 'rex', 'potato', 'sid')
walle = ('walle', 'eve', 'axiom', 'captain')
'-'.join([random.choice(toystory), random.choice(walle)])
```

Of course, ideally with much longer lists. And you can still throw in a number part at the end, for example:

```
'-'.join([random.choice(toystory), random.choice(walle), ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in xrange(3))])
```

Finally, take a look at [PEP8, the style guide of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). So far your code is ok, but it's recommended to indent with 4 spaces instead of 2. There is a command line tool called `pep8` which can check your code for style. As you're learning Python, it's good to follow the recommended style right from the start, easier than correcting bad habits later.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the style guide. The second entry is an Emerson quote so I think I'm going to like it.The domain names wont be managed by humans so remembering them won't be a problem.